# Comment appelle-t-on ce qui n'a pas de contraire?

Tags: antonyme

Comment pourrait-on qualifier un concept qui n'a pas de contraire, comme par exemple celui de "*profondeur"*, ou des mots n'ayant pas d'antonymes comme "*cher*", ou "*confiance*".

La question m'est venue lors de la recherche d'une traduction en "un mot" de "*untrusted*" (quelque chose qui n'est pas forcément digne confiance).

Comment: confiance → défiance, cher → abordable, profond → superficiel

Comment: Les exemples choisis ne sont peut-être pas les meilleurs, mais les disqualifier ne répond pas à la question. Ou alors il faudrait faire une réponse défendant l'idée qu'il n'existe aucun mot en français sans son contraire.

Comment: ***trusthworthy*** and ***untrustworthy***: digne et  pas digne de confiance. Untrusted n'est pas cela. Untrusted veut dire: une personne qui n'est pas de confiance. Le mot untrusted n'est pas très usité.

Comment: On l'utilise aussi pour dire qu'un document n'a pas été officiellement approuvé. "Pas digne de confiance" peut s'appliquer à une personne ou une chose. Dans quel sens devrait-on corriger pour coller mieux à la définition?

Comment: @Lambie Sur internet explorer, quand un certificat n'est pas valide, il est qualifié de untrusted dans le message d'erreur. Mais ma question porte surtout sur l'absence de concept, je justifiais juste ma question (mais mal)

Comment: @pwnsauce Pourquoi des mots qui n'ont pas d'antonyme auraient-ils un qualificatif?? Pourquoi pas dire: des mots sans antonyme??

Comment: @Lambie, ben ont a des qualificatifs pour pleins de choses, j'imaginais qu'il y en avait un pour ca aussi.

Answer (score 7):

Un mot qui n'as pas de contraire, plus particulièrement un vocable avec un préfixe, mais dont le mot de base "n'existe pas", est connu en linguistique comme un *unpaired word* ("mot non apparié"?). De manière plus générale, on parle de *semantic* ou *lexical gap* ("absence lexicale"?).

Ils sont plus communs en anglais (à cause d'emprunts ou d'archaïsme) qu'en français, où ils sont généralement dus à une création lexicale combinant plusieurs préfixe simultanément: ***Dépuceler*** est un rare exemple qu'il est difficile de remettre en question.

Nombre de mots en in+verbe+[a]ble (*illisible, immangeable*) on été considérés comme appartenant à cette catégorie par les dictionnaires, mais dans les fait cela dépend fondamentalement du vocable en question. Peut être *intenable* en ferait-il partie.

Comment: Merci Circeus, très intéressant. Jamais entendu parler de ce concept dans le monde francophone, et je n'arrive même pas à retrouver ce terme en français. On dirait que c'est surtout utilisé dans le monde anglo-saxon? Ils semblent avoir ce problème, du fait que beaucoup de mots sont empruntés au français, et n'ont pas été directement forgés dans la langue.

Comment: Souffle, âme, au moins pour ces deux là, le site antonym.org ne donne pas de réponse.

Comment: Ce pourrait être des ***mononymes***

Comment: untrusted is not an unpaired word.  Le mot de base existe ici: **trust**.

Comment: Le contraire de dépuceler est l'[hyménoplastie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hym%C3%A9noplastie).

Answer (score 3):

"Profondeur", "cher", "confiance", possèdent des contraires.

La profondeur: la superficialité.

Ça dépend du contexte de la phrase et du sens de "*profondeur*", profondeur intellectuelle, profondeur de l'eau, profondeur spirituelle, etc...

Cher: Cela dépend aussi du sens du mot "*cher*", le mot étant très polysémique. Cher, dans le sens qui coûte cher? Alors c'est "bon marché", " C'est en deux mots, mais ça ne fait aucune différence, et on peut aussi utiliser des périphrases, cela ne veut pas dire que le concept n'existe pas. On peut aussi en trouver bien d'autres, avantageux, etc...

Je n'ai pas bien compris le lien avec "untrustable". Peu digne de confiance. Cela dépend vraiment du contexte. Il faudrait fournir un contexte pour avoir l'antonyme idéal, dans un contexte donné.

Pour revenir à la première question, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait des concepts qui n'aient pas de contraire. Par définition, si une chose existe, un concept existe, c'est que son absence existe aussi, en tout cas en linguistique, pas forcément en métaphysique.

Ensuite, pour répondre à la suite, on ne peut trouver d'antonymes que si le sens est vraiment précisé par un contexte.

Comment: Que tous les concepts aient leur contraire, même si cela resterait à démontrer, c'est une chose que l'on peut admettre. Mais ici il s'agit de mots. Que dire des mots dont le contraire ne peut être exprimé que par une périphrase ou un groupe de mots ?

Comment: Je ne sais pas s'il y a un mot pour ça. Mais un mot, ou un groupe de mots, ça revient au même. Quand on a cheap = bon marché, par exemple, que "bon marché" soit un mot, ou deux, ça n'affaiblit pas le "concept".

Comment: Regarde la réponse de Circeus, elle est extrêmement intéressante.

Comment: Pour superficialité, je trouve pas que ca soit le contraire de profondeur. C'est plutôt l'absence de profondeur. Donc tous les concepts ont un concept contraire?

Comment: ça dépend du contexte! Je pense que si un concept existe, on peut imaginer son absence, donc la conceptualiser. En philosophie, il n'en va pas de même.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais "un mot incontrariable" comme par exemple le mot : cosmique!

Comment: Bienvenue sur FSE.  C'est un néologisme ?  C'est créatif.

Comment: @livresque Oui, mais un vieux ! *Dictionnaire de mots nouveau*, Jean Baptiste Richard de Radonvilliers , 1845. https://books.google.fr/books?id=FOQSAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA285&ots=mz3D54QPkY&dq=incontrariable&hl=fr&pg=PA285#v=onepage&q=incontrariable&f=false